# R Shiny: How to select a DataTable page based on a selected row when the row order has changed?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to highlight a row of a datatable in a Shiny app based on a marker clicked on a leaflet map. To do so I have to change the page and go to page 5 if row 46 is selected for example.

It works fine if I do not change the rows order.

[image]

If I reorder the rows (for example on ascending `val`), I cannot find a way to go to the page corresponding to the selected row.

I have [ckecked the dataTableProxy manual](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DT/versions/0.2/topics/dataTableProxy) but it  has not helped.

Any help would be much appreciated.

A code example you can run:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    leafletOutput("Map"),
    dataTableOutput("Table")
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(DT)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  nbpts <- 50
  center <- c(47,3)
  ref <- 1:nbpts
  lat <- rnorm(nbpts, center[1], 2)
  lng <- rnorm(nbpts, center[2], 2)
  val <- sin(lat+lng)

  data <- data.frame(ref, lat, lng,val)

  output$Table <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data, selection = "single")
  })

  TableProxy <-  dataTableProxy("Table")

  output$Map <- renderLeaflet({
    data_map <- leaflet(data) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(
        lng=~lng,
        lat=~lat,
        layerId = ~ref,
        radius = 4,
        color = "purple",
        stroke = FALSE,
        fillOpacity = 0.5
      )
    data_map
  })

  observeEvent(input$Map_marker_click, {
    clickId <- input$Map_marker_click$id
    dataId <- which(data$ref == clickId)
    TableProxy %>%
      selectRows(dataId) %>%
      selectPage(dataId %/% 10 + 1)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that for the rows you should filter for the `ref` number and the page number you should calculate with the help of the actual row number.

This should help you:

```
  observeEvent(input$Map_marker_click, {
      clickId <- input$Map_marker_click$id
      dataTableProxy("Table") %>%
      selectRows(which(data$ref == clickId)) %>%
      selectPage(which(input$Table_rows_all == clickId) %/% 10 + 1)
  })
```

Upvote, because the question was quite interesting.

**Edit:**
Credits to NicE for the hint for the dynamic table length variable, see the comments.

```
   output$Table <- renderDataTable({
       DT::datatable(data, selection = "single",options=list(stateSave = TRUE))
   })

   observeEvent(input$Map_marker_click, {
      clickId <- input$Map_marker_click$id
      dataTableProxy("Table") %>%
      selectRows(which(data$ref == clickId)) %>%
      selectPage(which(input$Table_rows_all == clickId) %/% input$Table_state$length + 1)
  })
```

Comment: You could also replace the `10` (rows per page) by `input$Table_state$length` to make this responsive to users changing that parameter. (This requires `stateSave=TRUE` in the datatable call, `DT::datatable(data, selection = "single",options=list(stateSave = TRUE))` )